# Can you confirm these DEFCON verbs for Twilight Struggle?

Tags: twilight-struggle

For example, DEFCON is currently at 3.  Due to some trigger (event card, end of turn, etc.) it needs to move.  Can you confirm my understanding of the verbs?

---

**INCREASE**: Move DEFCON to left to 4

**IMPROVE**:  Move DEFCON to left to 4

**DECREASE**: Move DEFCON to right to 2

**DEGRADE**:  Move DEFCON to right to 2

**LOWER**:    Move DEFCON to right to 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got them straight.  The rule book uses all of those terms.

---

The rules are pretty clear on improve, decrease, degrade, and lower:

> 4.5 A. *Improve* DEFCON Status: If the DEFCON level is *lower* than 5, add one to the DEFCON status (towards Peace).
>
> 6.3.4 Any Coup attempt in a Battleground country *degrade*s the DEFCON status one level (towards Nuclear War).
>
> 8.1.1 DEFCON status measures nuclear tension in the game. The DEFCON level begins the game at its maximum ‘peace’ level of 5. It can go down and back up due to events and actions by the players, but if, at any point, it *decrease*s to , the game ends immediately.

The Extended Playthrough uses increase:

> **TURN 2**
>
> (DEFCON *increase*s to 3, Mil Ops requirements met by both players, no lost points)

[Emphasis added to rule citations]

Comment: Good.  I wish the publisher would just use 1 verb for going left, and 1 verb for going right.  The "lower" verb was the main verb that threw me off.  Depending how you think about it, it could be interpreted either way.  Thanks for the reply.